# In UIViewController how can I have a single method automatically handle a lot of buttons

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` for an iPad app where the user can pick one of 80 puzzles by touching one of 80 buttons. Rather than manually connect 80 `UIButton` to an `IBAction` method, is there any way to do this programmatically or in some other clever way?

Another option of course to build a custom view and do all the work myself but I would like to know if the above can be made easier.

Comment: Google:" uitableview SQLite" I would give you more on SQLite, but I'm a noob using it myself.  It'll make your life a million times easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this might work:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{

for ( UIView* potentialButton in view.subviews )
{
  if ( [potentialButton isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]] )
  {
     UIButton* actualButton = (UIButton*) potentialButton;
     [actualButton addTarget: self action: @selector( onButtonPress: ) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   }
}

...

}

- (void) onButtonPress: (UIButton*) sender
{
  // determine which button here, by tag, or perhaps by button title, etc.
}
```

Comment: Yup I wound up doing exactly that!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean 80 UIButtons to 80 actions or 80 buttons to 1 action?
You could add all the buttons programmatically using this:
.h

```
 @interface myfile : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[button setTitle:@"1" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake (x position, y position, width, height);
 [button addTarget:self action: @selector(myaction:) forControlEvents :UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView:button];

}
```

And all other buttons linked to one action called:

```
-(IBAction)myaction:(id)sender {
switch([sender tag])
case 1:
//open puzzle 1
break;
case 2:
//open puzzle 2
break;
...
default:
break;
}
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

You can list the objects (subviews) in a view to find all your buttons.  Of course, you'll need to weed out other objects somehow.

You can do addTarget for the buttons to set their action methods.

Every action method receives a pointer to the UI object.  You just need to compare the pointer to your list of objects to figure out which one it is.

Comment: or the control's tag property can be used for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Interface Builder will let you connect 80 objects to 1 method, and I think you might be able to do it all at once with multiple select (I will double-check.)  Then, within that method, you can use the (id)sender value to determine which button it is; for example, by saying

```
if([[[(UIButton*)sender titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"Puzzle 1"]){
    // open puzzle 1
}
```

If your titles are consecutive, you could loop through them:

```
NSString* senderTitle =  [[(UIButton*)sender titleLabel] text];

for(int i=1; i<=80; i++){
    if([senderTitle isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Puzzle %d",i]]){
         // open puzzle i
    }
}
```

Comment: oops - I just checked - you can't add multiple senders with Interface Builder.  However, as other answers have pointed out, you could loop through them in viewDidLoad and addTarget: to each one. `[obj addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`
`